# In TraMineR seqiplot, how do I change the numbers on the y axis to labels?

Tags: r, traminer

```
library('TraMineR')
data(mvad)
mvad.labels <- c("employment", "further education", "higher education",
                    "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.scodes <- c("EM","FE","HE","JL","SC","TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad, 15:86, states=mvad.scodes, labels=mvad.labels)
seqiplot(mvad.seq, withlegend=F)
```

produces [image]

I'd like to label the 1st sequence as "2015_NSWDC_2", and so on. Is that possible?

Comment: here you go! Hope this makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

Customized labels can be specified in `seqiplot` with the `ytlab` argument.

Perhaps the most convenient way consists in first assigning the labels as row names of the state sequence object and then specifying `ytlab="id"` to use the row names as y-labels. For example:

```
rownames(mvad.seq) <- paste0("seq",rownames(mvad.seq))
seqiplot(mvad.seq, ytlab = "id", ylas=1)
```

The `ylas=1` option is to display the labels horizontally.

Alternatively, you can pass directly the label vector as `ytlab` argument

```
mylabels <- paste0('y', 1:10)
seqiplot(mvad.seq, withlegend=F, ytlab=mylabels, ylas=1)
```

Note that due to a bug in`TraMineR` 1.8.11, the latter solution generates a warning that can simply be ignored.